# AS3: Calculating the exact height of 3D rotated object

Tags: actionscript-3, matrix, projection

I am trying to calculate the exact height of a 3D rotated shape and take into account its `perspectiveProjection`. I realize there are a number of ways to get a good approximation, like using `localToGlobal`, or even just using it's `height` property, but all of those methods return an integer, and I need something more precise. Here is a more detailed explanation of the problem:

[image: rotations]
Consider this red box and the black bar which is my attempt at calculating the exact height:

```
const w:Number = 100, h:Number = 100;
var redBox:Shape = new Shape();
redBox.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
redBox.graphics.drawRect(-w/2,0,w,h);
redBox.graphics.endFill();
redBox.x = 100;
redBox.y = 200;
addChild(redBox);
redBox.rotationX = -45;

var heightBar:Shape = new Shape();
var heightBarH:Number = Math.cos(redBox.rotationX*Math.PI/180)*h; // ≈70.71
heightBar.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
heightBar.graphics.drawRect(0,0,10,heightBarH);
heightBar.graphics.endFill();
heightBar.x = redBox.x + 100;
heightBar.y = redBox.y;
addChild(heightBar);
```

As redBox.rotationX approaches -90, heightBarH goes to 0, which is what you would expect if there was no perspectiveProjection. As you can see, the height of redBox does not approach 0 because of this perspectiveProjection. I am trying to calculate heightBarH while taking the perspectiveProjection into account.

It seems the only way to calculate the exact height would be to have a `Vector.<Number>` of the x, y, and z coordinates of the shape's vertices, apply the rotation to a `matrix3D` and project the vertices to points, but I have not had any success with that method.

```
var verts:Vector.<Number> = new <Number>[
    -w/2,0,0,
    -w/2,h,0,
    w/2,h,0,
    w/2,0,0,
    -w/2,0,0
];
var pVerts:Vector.<Number> = new <Number>[];
var uv:Vector.<Number> = new <Number>[];
var matrix3D:Matrix3D = root.transform.perspectiveProjection.toMatrix3D();
matrix3D.identity(); //Not sure why I need to do this, but my matrix3D will be full of Infinity and NaN if I don't.
matrix3D.appendRotation(45,Vector3D.X_AXIS);
Utils3D.projectVectors(matrix3D, verts, pVerts, uv);
var drawnShape:Shape = new Shape();
drawnShape.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
var shape_commands:Vector.<int> = new <int> [
    GraphicsPathCommand.MOVE_TO,
    GraphicsPathCommand.LINE_TO,
    GraphicsPathCommand.LINE_TO,
    GraphicsPathCommand.LINE_TO,
    GraphicsPathCommand.LINE_TO,
];
drawnShape.graphics.drawPath(shape_commands,pVerts);
drawnShape.graphics.endFill();
drawnShape.x = stage.stageWidth/2;
drawnShape.y = stage.stageHeight/2;
addChild(drawnShape);
```

This does not seem to result in a shape with the correct perspectiveProjection either. Any insight would be appreciated.